# I get a websocket '426 upgrade required' error

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I am total new to websocket.

I get the follow error:

> 426 upgrade required

I search on the Internet but don't find the solution.

My both scripts:

node.js:

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

// Verbinding met de database
const dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost', // Jouw database hostnaam
  user: '*',   // Jouw database gebruikersnaam
  password: '*', // Jouw database wachtwoord
  database: '*' // Jouw database naam
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8091 });

let clientConnections = new Set();

// Functie om nieuwe meldingen naar alle geopende WebSocket-verbindingen te sturen
function sendNotificationsToClients(message) {
    clientConnections.forEach(ws => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            ws.send(message);
        }
    });
}

// Functie om de database te controleren op nieuwe meldingen
async function checkForNewNotifications() {
    try {
        const [rows] = await dbConnection.promise().query('SELECT * FROM tabel');
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            const latestNotification = rows[rows.length - 1];
            const notificationJson = JSON.stringify(latestNotification);
            sendNotificationsToClients(notificationJson);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Fout bij het ophalen van meldingen:', error.message);
    }
}

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Client connected');

    clientConnections.add(ws);

    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
        clientConnections.delete(ws);
    });
});

// Interval voor het controleren van nieuwe meldingen en verzenden naar clients
setInterval(() => {
    checkForNewNotifications();
}, 5000); // Controleer elke 5 seconden op nieuwe meldingen
```

My internet script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>P2000 Meldingen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>P2000 Meldingen</h1>
    <div id="messageContainer"></div>

    <script>
        const messageContainer = document.getElementById('messageContainer');

        // Configuratie voor WebSocket met handmatige headers
        const ws = new WebSocket('wss://**:8091/', [], {
            headers: {
                'Connection': 'Upgrade',
                'Upgrade': 'websocket',
                'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13'
            }
        });

        ws.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
            console.log('WebSocket connected');
        });

        ws.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            const message = data.message;
            // Hier kun je de ontvangen gegevens verwerken en weergeven op jouw webpagina
            messageContainer.innerHTML = message;
        });

        ws.addEventListener('close', function(event) {
            console.log('WebSocket disconnected');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

I try multiple solutions from Google. And I expect to get new messages through websocket from my database.

Comment: What web browser are you using that supports 3 parameters in the client `WebSocket`'s constructor?  Most implementations that follow the WebSocket API standard do not allow you to specify custom HTTP headers.